# What is the cheapest way to create a right triangle out of a square dowel rod or similar?

Tags: dowel, rip-cut

I'm working on adding internal lighting to my pantry, and have discovered that the LED strips really only work when held at a 45 degree angle to the bottom of a shelf. I'd like to get a dowel rod and cut it into two dowel rods, each being a right triangle in cross-section, such that I could attach the led strips to the hypotenuse of that triangle. I have some woodworking tools from my dad (skill saw, circular saw, miter saw, reciprocating saw), but little to no experience beyond "saw this 2x4" or "cut this plywood to this size"

I think if I tried to use any of these tools, I would probably not get a decently straight line down the dowel, so I'm hesitant to try. What tools could I use to rip this dowel rod in this way? That being said, I'm not really interested in wood working as a hobby, so I don't want to invest in the most expensive way to accomplish this task, I'd like to do it with either the tools I have or relatively inexpensive tools. I'd like to avoid going out and buying say, a table saw.

For reference, I'm using a [1/2" square dowel](https://www.menards.com/main/home-decor/craft-supplies/dowels-wooden-pins-plugs/madison-mill-1-2-x-36-poplar-square-dowel/p-1444438754821-c-12188.htm?tid=-8686804353217824565) that I will be cutting to 12'' long.

Comment: What is the width & depth of your dowel?

Comment: @Ashlar 1/2" x 1/2" x 12". Question updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can buy what you need already fabricated. Search "champfer strip". Here's a Home Depot link: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Alexandria-Moulding-3-4-in-x-3-4-in-Pine-Chamfer-Strip-Moulding-0W995-200RLC/206844349 If the 3/4" x 3/4" is too fat, here's a link to 1/2": https://www.patterson-online.com/itemdetail/WC1210

I'm sure you can find other options as well from a more thorough search.

Answer (score 6):

I would not want to start with 1/2" x 1/2" square stock unless you have a table saw.  Trying to rip small stock with the tools you listed would be quite difficult (and dangerous).

Instead, start with a bigger piece of stock, say 1x6.  Mark a line 1/2" in from one edge.  Put your circular saw at a 45 degree bevel and rip along that line.